# Can Windows 7 Ultimate x64 bit support DDR4 RAM

Tags: windows

Like the tittle says, can it? Because I'm planing to buy 32GB RAM DDR4 and Windows 7 Pro x64 bit and I don't want to buy it and not be worth it.

Comment: The right question would be : is your motherboard can support this RAM format ? Btw, Windows 7 x64 will support 32Gb of RAM.

Comment: @Ob1lan It depends. See [Physical Memory Limits: Windows 7](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_7). By the way none of them have 32Gb as the answer ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill , your post suggest that his computer running Windows 7 Ultimate x64 could support up to 192Gb of RAM... SO yeah, it could support 32Gb... I can't see the point of your comment...

Comment: My point is it can support **more** than 32 Gb if he wants to.

Comment: Out of curiosity only, why do you need 32 GB RAM?

Comment: DDR4 compatability is determined by hardware not software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can update to 32GB, until and unless your mother board supports DDR4 RAM. There is a difference in key notch position.

[image]

image courtesy : [pcgameware.co.uk](http://www.pcgameware.co.uk/images/DDR-4-slot-difference.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The motherboard is what will limit the use of the new RAM sticks!

Your question is `Can Windows 7 Ultimate x64 bit support DDR4 RAM`

Yes, Windows 7 64 bit can use the DDR4 RAM. In fact, here is a video showing it in action https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tdzMJncY1us

And a link to a manufacturer website showing the benchmarks of Windows 7 and DDR4 RAM https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/X99DELUXE/